# How to show the latest value in card in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, measure

I have the following chart which shows sick leave per person for July and August and on top of that is a card that shows the average of all the months, so in this case is average of July and August which gives 1.55.

[image]

Instead of the average, I want the card to show the latest value of the month, so in this case I want the card to show August value which is 0.79 and when September data is loaded, I want the card to show September data instead, unless someone clicks on a different month, then the card should update to show average of what they selected.

Answer (score 0):

For the measure to show the latest months data you could do something like this

```
Latest Month Average =
VAR latest_month =
    MONTH ( CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[SickDate] ) ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGEX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Person] ), COUNT ( 'Table'[SickDate] ) ),
        FILTER ( 'Table', MONTH ( 'Table'[SickDate] ) = latest_month )
    )
```

Im not sure what you're data looks like so im making assumptions based on your visual
So im assuming a table like this

| Person | SickDate |
| --- | --- |
| Jim | Thursday, 1 September 2022 |
| Jane | Thursday, 1 September 2022 |
| John | Saturday, 1 October 2022 |
| Jim | Thursday, 1 September 2022 |
| Jane | Thursday, 1 September 2022 |
| John | Saturday, 1 October 2022 |
| Phil | Sunday, 2 October 2022 |

So the measure basically gets the latest month in the data
Counts the amount of dates (sick days) by person and takes an average

Note: if you're showing multiple years you would need to get the latest month and year to filter correctly and not just month